# Scrape data after button click in PuppeteerSharp C#

Tags: c#, puppeteer, chromium, puppeteer-sharp

I am unable to scrape data after clicking the button in Puppeteer Sharp C#.

Here is my Puppeteer C# code:

```
string url = $"https://www.google.com";
var response = await page.GoToAsync(url, new NavigationOptions
{
   Timeout = 0,
   WaitUntil = waitUntil
});
if (response.Status == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
  await page.TypeAsync("input[name=q]", "Mukarram Javid Github");
  await page.Keyboard.PressAsync("Enter");

  await page.WaitForNavigationAsync();
  
  var content = await page.EvaluateExpressionAsync("document.querySelector('#res')");
}
```

I did not get any data in `content`. Can anybody let me know this solution?

I want to scrape the following content - see the screenshot.

Regards,

[image]

Comment: `querySelector` won't return any content

Comment: Should I use `querySelectorAll` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I used `querySelectorAll`. My issue has been resolved.

```
var  content = await page.EvaluateExpressionAsync("document.querySelectorAll('#res')");
```